# Trazer dados do intervalo

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Gostaria de trazer até mesmo as onde não estivesse valor na consulta
Por exemplo;

tabela **dados**

```
id    |   valor  |   data
 1    |   5      |   01/10/2018
 2    |   6      |   03/10/2018
 3    |   7      |   04/10/2018
 5    |   8      |   05/10/2018
```

Gostaria que quando fizesse uma consulta

```
SELECT * FROM dados WHERE data BETWEEN '01/10/018' AND '06/10/2018'
```

Viesse o dia **02/10/2018** e o dia **06/10/2018** mesmo que sem os dados

```
id    |   valor  |   data
 1    |   5      |   01/10/2018
      |   null   |   02/10/2018
 2    |   6      |   03/10/2018
 3    |   7      |   04/10/2018
 5    |   8      |   05/10/2018
      |   null   |   06/10/2018
```

Tem como?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa listar as datas em um `sub-select` e fazer o `LEFT JOIN` para listar todas:

```
SELECT dados.id, dados.valor, datas.data
FROM (
    SELECT '2018-10-01' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '2018-10-02' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '2018-10-03' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '2018-10-04' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '2018-10-05' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '2018-10-06' AS data
) AS datas
LEFT JOIN dados ON dados.data = datas.data
```

Caso sua coluna `data` da tabela `dados` não esteja no formato `date`, você precisará fazer assim:

```
SELECT dados.id, dados.valor, datas.data
FROM (
    SELECT '01/10/2018' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '02/10/2018' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '03/10/2018' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '04/10/2018' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '05/10/2018' AS data
    UNION
    SELECT '06/10/2018' AS data
) AS datas
LEFT JOIN dados ON dados.data = datas.data
```

Comment: Mas teria que ser na mão mesmo, né?

Comment: Sim, teria que ser na mão.

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta

Comment: E se viesse de um campo de uma tela?

Comment: Ai você precisaria pegar a data inicial e ir incrementando até chegar a data final.